# how to fix this error ? gradle's configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android studio 1.5.1 and when I create a new project this error message appears. So haw can I fix that error ?:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-xmx1024m

[image: Screenshots android studio 1.5.1]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line at the end of your application `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

If this doesnt work try this..

Start Android studio

On Welcome window, Go to Configure > Settings

Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

Change Build process heap size to 1024 and Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m.

Restart Android Studio.